# I have problems with morphiaSessionFactory for morphia 2.1x

Tags: mongodb, java-11

It's morphiaSessionFactory for morphia 1.5

```
public static Datastore morphiaSessionFactoryUtil() {
        MongoClientOptions.Builder options = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
        // set your connection option here
        MongoClient mongoClient;
        try {
          MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(properties.getProperty("mongoURI"));
          mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("Can't connect with URI. Fallback to host/port config");
          options.connectionsPerHost(200); // max pool size
          mongoClient =
              new MongoClient(
                  new ServerAddress(
                      properties.getProperty("dbBaseUrl"),
                      Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("dbBasePort"))),
                  options.build());
        }
        
        Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
        morphia.getMapper().getOptions().setStoreEmpties(true);
        morphia.mapPackage("io.itgen.model");
        return morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, properties.getProperty("dbName"));
      }
```

Now I want to use morphia 2.1 but don't know how replace this method. Problems with last 4 lines.